# How to access member variable with gcc inline assembler code

Tags: c++, gcc, arduino, avr, inline-assembly

So I've recently stumbled across the blog post 
[NeoPixels Revealed: How to (not need to) generate precisely timed signals](https://wp.josh.com/2014/05/13/ws2812-neopixels-are-not-so-finicky-once-you-get-to-know-them/) and supporting [github project](https://github.com/bigjosh/SimpleNeoPixelDemo) and am now trying to encapsulate the heart of this code into a c++ class so that I can access various neopixel strings from multiple arduino uno digital pins.

To do this, I've created a protected member variable (m_PixelChannel) which stores the pin required to access the light string. However, I can't get the assembly code to recognize the member variable. Below is the code that I'm trying to make work (which is more-or-less a direct copy-paste of the original code from the github project with a classname added before it):

```
// send a bit to the string. We must to drop to asm to enusre that the complier does
// not reorder things and make it so the delay happens in the wrong place.
inline void fastNeoPixels::sendBit(bool bitVal) {

  if (bitVal) { // 0 bit
    asm volatile(
        "sbi %[port], %[bit] \n\t" // Set the output bit
        ".rept %[onCycles] \n\t"   // Execute NOPs to delay exactly the specified number of cycles
        "nop \n\t"
        ".endr \n\t"
        "cbi %[port], %[bit] \n\t" // Clear the output bit
        ".rept %[offCycles] \n\t"  // Execute NOPs to delay exactly the specified number of cycles
        "nop \n\t"
        ".endr \n\t" ::
        [port] "I"(_SFR_IO_ADDR(PIXEL_PORT)),
        [bit] "r"(m_PixelChannel),
        // [bit] "I" (PIXEL_STRING0),
        [onCycles] "I"(NS_TO_CYCLES(T1H) - 2), // 1-bit width less overhead  for the actual bit setting, note that this delay could be longer and everything would still work
        [offCycles] "I"(NS_TO_CYCLES(T1L) - 2) // Minimum interbit delay. Note that we probably don't need this at all since the loop overhead will be enough, but here for correctness
    );
  } else { // 1 bit
    // **************************************************************************
    // This line is really the only tight goldilocks timing in the whole program!
    // **************************************************************************
    asm volatile(
        "sbi %[port], %[bit] \n\t" // Set the output bit
        ".rept %[onCycles] \n\t"   // Now timing actually matters. The 0-bit must be long enough to be detected but not too long or it will be a 1-bit
        "nop \n\t"                 // Execute NOPs to delay exactly the specified number of cycles
        ".endr \n\t"
        "cbi %[port], %[bit] \n\t" // Clear the output bit
        ".rept %[offCycles] \n\t"  // Execute NOPs to delay exactly the specified number of cycles
        "nop \n\t"
        ".endr \n\t" ::
        [port] "I"(_SFR_IO_ADDR(PIXEL_PORT)),
        [bit] "r" (m_PixelChannel),
        // [bit] "I" (PIXEL_STRING0),
        [onCycles] "I"(NS_TO_CYCLES(T0H) - 2),
        [offCycles] "I"(NS_TO_CYCLES(T0L) - 2)
    );
  }  // if (bitVal)...

  // Note that the inter-bit gap can be as long as you want as long as it doesn't exceed the 5us reset timeout (which is A long time)
  // Here I have been generous and not tried to squeeze the gap tight but instead erred on the side of lots of extra time.
  // This has thenice side effect of avoid glitches on very long strings becuase
}
```

I'm convinced that it is that m_PixelChannel variable causing the problems; something to do with the constraints I suppose, becuase I can get it to work again by uncommenting the PIXEL_STRING0 line of code. Alternatively, I could pass the value as a parameter to the method and use the "n" constraint code to get it working (as I have successfully done) but I don't think I should have to pass a parameter to a method that has access to the value already...

I've tried the following constraint codes, with no luck: "n", "o", "I", "m", "+m", "r" and "g".

Obviously I am missing something. Can someone, please, point me in the right direction to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that I really didn't like the template<> approach that I used in the comment to Chris Dodd's response. So after a number of iterations, I was able to figure out how to make it work...

```
  void sendBit( bool bitVal ) {
    volatile uint8_t _hi   = *m_PixelPORT |  m_PinMask;
    volatile uint8_t _lo   = *m_PixelPORT & ~m_PinMask;
    if ( bitVal ) {
      asm volatile (
        "st %a[port], %[hi]"  "\n\t"        // Set the output bit
        ".rept %[onCycles]"  "\n\t"   // Execute NOPs to delay exactly the specified number of cycles
        "nop"                "\n\t"   
        ".endr"              "\n\t"  
        "st %a[port], %[lo]"  "\n\t"   // Clear the output bit
        ".rept %[offCycles]" "\n\t"   // Execute NOPs to delay exactly the specified number of cycles
        "nop"                "\n\t"
        ".endr"              "\n\t"
        : [port] "+e" (m_PixelPORT)
        : [hi] "r" (_hi),
          [lo] "r" (_lo),
          [onCycles] "I" (NS_TO_CYCLES(T1H) - 2), // 1-bit width less overhead  for the actual bit setting, note that this delay could be longer and everything would still work
          [offCycles] "I" (NS_TO_CYCLES(T1L) - 2) // Minimum interbit delay. Note that we probably don't need this at all since the loop overhead will be enough, but here for correctness
      );
    } else {
      asm volatile (
        "st %a[port], %[hi]"  "\n\t"        // Set the output bit
        ".rept %[onCycles]"  "\n\t"   // Execute NOPs to delay exactly the specified number of cycles
        "nop"                "\n\t"   
        ".endr"              "\n\t"  
        "st %a[port], %[lo]"  "\n\t"   // Clear the output bit
        ".rept %[offCycles]" "\n\t"   // Execute NOPs to delay exactly the specified number of cycles
        "nop"                "\n\t"
        ".endr"              "\n\t"
        : [port] "+e" (m_PixelPORT)
        : [hi] "r" (_hi),
          [lo] "r" (_lo),
          [onCycles] "I" (NS_TO_CYCLES(T0H) - 2),
          [offCycles]   "I" (NS_TO_CYCLES(T0L) - 2)
      );
    }
  }
```

Where ***m_PinMask = _BV(digital_pin);***

Notice that the calls to ***sbi/cbi*** have been replaced by calls to ***st*** and the changes in the constraint-types.

Applying these changes has the code doing exactly what I'm wanting to do while staying within the timing requirements for the bit-bang process.

Thanks again to Chris for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Why are `_hi` and `_lo` `volatile`?  Forcing the compiler to spill them, and reload  on every read, makes no sense unless the asm statement itself is supposed to modify those local variable.  But it doesn't look like that's what's happening.

Comment: You could use `if (__builtin_constant_p(bitval))` to use more optimal asm for the case where `bitval` can match an `"I"` constraint.  (Works with gcc, but not clang.  Clang evaluates `__builtin_constant_p` before inlining so it's always false for wrapper functions like this.

Comment: @PeterCordes Both of these comments seem like things an experienced AVR programmer would be concerned with. That, unfortunately, is not me. I'm still learning all of the ins-and-outs of Arduino itself. Fortunately, I've got years of C++ experience, so that helps; but AVR assembly? Not so much.  I simply thought that volatile only forced the value into a register without requiring some kind of MOV operation first. If you say I don't need it and that it's detrimental to have it as volatile, then I'll change the code to see if it still works. Thanks.  - Jump

Comment: `volatile` forces variables into *memory*, not registers.  You don't need `volatile` on your locals, only the `asm volatile` statements.  They can read ordinary non-volatile locals (that's the normal use-case), and it's totally fine if the compiler keeps those locals in registers or whatever it wants to do.  You can look at the compiler's asm output to see how it filled in the template, and what instructions the compiler chose to put before/after your asm statements.  (Enable optimization).

Comment: In asm terms, a normal local var is a register.  You want to use that for the results of a `volatile uint8_t *m_PixelPORT` MMIO pointer or something.  What you need is a pointer-to-volatile, not to store the result in a `volatile` local.  https://godbolt.org/z/N01TVo (AVR G++ 5.4) shows how much more bloated the total asm is for this function if you uncomment `volatile` (which I commented there).

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the link. Yes it does change the code; almost to the point where my original code is unrecognizable. Wow. I have now learned something new today. Thanks!

Comment: Using `st`, you are writing to the entire port so there is a risk that you might overwrite any changes done to the GPIOs during an interrupt routine.  If you decide to go back to the template approach, you could just use this library: https://github.com/pololu/pololu-led-strip-arduino

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the operands to the SBI instruction must be constants (immediate values).  So the only constraint that works is `I` and the value has to be a constant.  There's no way to set a variable bit.

If you want to set a variable bit, you have to use something like a switch statement to select one of 8 different instructions.

Comment: While this is unfortunately true, I just couldn't bring myself to over-complicate the code with a bunch of switch() statements (that function would have required four swiitch()'s - each with 8 cases). So instead, I made the class a template<> class as such: template <int PORT_PIN> class...{}; and replaced the [bit] specific input constraint with [bit] "I" (PORT_PIN) which would be known at compile time. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction; that is in-fact what I asked for. :)

Comment: @jump: yes, using a template to make sure the value a compile-time constant even with optimization disabled is exactly the kind of approach the first half of this answer suggests.  You could maybe write a wrapper function with a `constexpr` arg that used its arg as a template param (or a CPP macro), letting you hide the template syntax from the use-cases.  That should all inline away to just the `sbi` with optimization enabled.